# Split text separated by lines starting with semicolon

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed, split

I have the output from a command (`plantuml -language`; see [List of keywords, predefined names, symbols for codeless language module for BBEdit?](https://forum.plantuml.net/10648/keywords-predefined-symbols-codeless-language-module-bbedit?show=10719]) for the background) which effectively looks like this:

```
;type1
;3
@fff
@ggg
hhh

;preprocessor
;1
!undef

;keyword
;3
!undef
test
somemore

.
.
.
```

The first `;` denotes the name, the second directly following `;` in the next line the number of items.
The items are followed by an empty line, and the next block begins.

I would like to split the whole output into separate files (named after the name), which I would like to process further.

File `type1`:

```
@fff
@ggg
hhh
```

File `preprocessor`:

```
!undef
```

File `keyword`:

```
!undef
test
somemore
```

How can I do this with tools like `awk` or `sed`? Or is there an easier tool?

Comment: Welcome to the site. To make it easier for contributors to help you, please edit your question to include an example of the desired output.

Comment: Thanks - I have done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but this seems to do it:

```
awk -F';' '
  NF==0 { next }
  NF>1 && $1=="" { filename=$2; getline; next }
  { print > filename }
' file
```

- If the number of fields is zero (blank line), continue with the next line.
- If the number of fields is greater one (a line starting with a semicolon), set variable `filename`, get the next line, but don't process it (skip it) and continue with the next line.
- Otherwise, print the line and redirect the output to the file `filename`.

Comment: Thanks. That works.

Comment: You will have a problem if any of the "data" lines *contains* a semicolon.

Comment: @glennjackman Good catch! I changed `NF>1` to `NF>1 && $1==""` to make it more robust.

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
awk -F '\n' -v RS= '{f=substr($1, 2); for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) print $i > f}' file
```

Note that in awk-speak, a file is composed of "records", and a record contains "fields". By default, a record == one line, but this can be configured.

This uses the input record separator `RS` variable as the empty string, which means that sequences of empty lines separate records. I set the field separator to newline. Together, each "paragraph" of the file is a record, and each line in a paragraph is a field.

The `substr` call just omits the leading semicolon.

I'm not actually checking that the number of lines of data is actually equal to the "n" value of the 2nd `;` line.